# sqlite3.OperationalError: near "'...'": syntax error

Tags: python, sqlite

**INPUT FILE:**

```
$ cat inputs.csv
'18-01-2019', 296.0
'18-01-2019', 296.0
'18-01-2019', 296.0
```

**CODE:**

```
import csv
import sqlite3
import pprint

conn = sqlite3.connect('metrics.db')
c = conn.cursor()

def read_file(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        yield from f

for row in read_file('inputs.csv'):

    data = row.split(',')
    values = '({}, {})'.format(data[0], data[1].strip())
    print('Values are: {}'.format(values))

    try:
        query = '\'INSERT INTO metric_db VALUES (?, ?)\', {}'.format(values)
        print('Query is: {}'.format(query))
        c.execute(query)
    except sqlite3.IntegrityError as e:
        pass

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

**OUTPUT ERROR:**

```
Values are: ('18-01-2019', 296.0)
Query is: 'INSERT INTO metric_db VALUES (?, ?)', ('18-01-2019', 296.0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "write_to_db.py", line 21, in <module>
    c.execute(query)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "'INSERT INTO metric_db VALUES (?, ?)'": syntax error
```

I thought this was easier. Quite a few SO threads on this error. But I am still not there yet :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your query statement:

```
query = 'INSERT INTO metric_db VALUES  {}'.format(values)
```

**EDIT**

To Avoid SQL injection and use correct date format:

```
import csv
import sqlite3
import pprint
from datetime import datetime

conn = sqlite3.connect('metrics.db')
c = conn.cursor()

def read_file(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        yield from f

for row in read_file('inputs.csv'):

    data = row.split(',')
    values = '({}, {})'.format(data[0], data[1].strip())
    print('Values are: {}'.format(values))
    date_readed = datetime.strptime(data[0], '%d-%m-%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

    try:
        query = 'INSERT INTO metric_db VALUES (?, ?)'
        c.execute(query,(date_readed,data[1],))
    except sqlite3.IntegrityError as e:
        pass

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Comment: This Works. What was wrong with date format? Any specific dateformat that sqlite prefers (or any other database  prefers?)

Comment: Yes, data base systems usually have the date format in yyyy-mm-dd, so when you try to insert in dd-mm-yyyy format they get an error.

Answer (score 0):

Check your schema.sql file. just try to copy-paste this file from tutorial.